# Realise circuit for hFe measurement

Tags: voltage, operational-amplifier, transistors, capacitor, ac

To measure Beta (hFe) of the transistor you should zero u_ce (voltage across CE for the AC component in signal). To zero that component you put capacitor in parallel with transistor AND as shown on the picture "b" a source of amplified (varying) signal ("e_g") in series with U_CC.

[image]

If I use my DC power supply to set Q point of the transistor, I plug it to black and red terminals on my little test board, then I should have "e_g" plugged right before a switch, so that pressing the button would apply DC + AC signal.

[image]

I know you can't do just that, as the voltage sources will eat each other, so how do I achieve that? Is the best option to use an op-amp, are there any possibilities available which do not involve op-amps?

Comment: WHich current gain test did you want?  (1) hFE @ Vce(sat) , (2) hFE @ Vce=Vbat/2,  (3) Hfe AC current gain vs Ic?

Comment: (3) I believe. I measured current Ic and Ib for varied DC source and computed Beta from that, I got results like 1 to 400. Now I would like to check if I get same beta in test "b" shown in the picture, as this i show you should measure Beta. And what test says is to use UCC to set transistor's operating point and then apply "e_g" in series with base, this is what I want.

Comment: That would be apparent DC gain (2) with variable Ic unless you computed incremental changes

Comment: According to the book the circuit from picture "b" is how to measure h21e parameter from hybrid model of transistor in common emitter configuration == beta == hFe from datasheets, isn't it?

Comment: It seems some details are missing

Comment: Dc gain is hFE, or Ic/Ib. Yes, a batch of the same transistors can have a wide range of gains, to us engineers bane. Darlingtons can be worse. Some datasheets just post the nominal average DC gain. It *looks* better that way.

Comment: \$\beta_\text{DC}=\frac{I_\text{C}}{I_\text{B}}\$ when operated at the values of \$I_\text{C}\$ and \$V_\text{CE}\$ that you expect to use. \$\beta_\text{AC}=\frac{I_{\text{C}_2}-I_{\text{C}_1}}{I_{\text{B}_2}-I_{\text{B}_1}}\$ where you select two nearby operating points. (And you do not need an opamp for any of this. It can be done with simple circuitry and simple meters.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised this circuit and got superimposed signal S = DC + "e_g" = 1 + sin(2*PI*10^4*t) by connecting grounds of two voltage sources together and their positive terminals to ground and positive of the circuit.

I also put capacitor in parallel with transistor as shown, for varying capacitance: 1uF, 100uF, 1000uF. The observed result of that is decrease in collector current from 0.37mA to 0.322mA.

Capacitor value | Collector current | Base current | Beta = Ic/Ib

- -,0.37mA, 1.2uA, 308
- 1uF, 0.35mA, 1.1uA, 318
- 100uF, 0.322mA, 1.1uA, 293
- 1000uF, 0.322mA, 1.1uA, 293

All currents measured with DC current function of multimeter. Resistance is 430 kOhm (bbutton to base) and 100 Ohm (Vcc to collector), transistor is 2N3904 with hFe300 in datasheet.

[image]

Comment: A po co w ogóle robiłeś takie pomiary ?  I za "e_g" robiła microswitch?

Comment: "e_g" = sin(2*PI*10^4*t) z generatora sygnałów, sinusoida 10kHz, 1V amplituda, 2V pp. Pomiary te wykonywałem w ramach ćwiczeń z tranzystorem

Comment: A to nie mogłaś zmierzyć bety (\$\beta = H_{FE}\$) z wykorzystaniem tylko prądu stałego? I tu sobie poczytaj https://forum.elportal.pl/viewtopic.php?p=87990#p87990

Comment: Chciałem ten dokładnie obwod zrealizować, również ze względu na problemy jakie napotkałem (źródła napięcia). Fajny, przydatny link - dziękuję bardzo.

Comment: A bardziej dokładnie z czym miałeś problem?

Comment: Ten post dotyczy problemu ze zrealizowaniem źródła napięcia AC + DC. Miałem kilka więcej problemów, ale w tym poście pytałem o źródła napięcia.

Comment: One thing I do not understand. Why did you use AC voltage source together with a DC source and do the measurement via a DC ammeter?  What is the point? Do you know the difference between DC current gain \$ \beta = H_{FE}\$ and AC current gain \$h_{fe} = h_{21e}\$? And what is all about the \$v_{ce} = 0V\$ stuff anyhow?

Comment: AC component's voltage is zeroed due to capacitor put in parallel with transistor. And why I used AC + DC is because that's what I wanted,  a signal of s(t) = 1 + sin(2*PI*10^4*t).